# List appending one object in loop. How do I rectify this error?

Tags: python, list, web-scraping, lxml, data-science

I am kinda new to this. The idea is to scrape data. I have a problem with some part of my code. The code runs perfectly but during the execution of 'print("The output is:",output)' as shown in the code below. I expect a list of objects. The result I get is just one object in the list. 
For example, I expect after running the code the output should be [resp, resp, ...], it only shows the last object to be executed in the loop as : [resp]. 
An example of my output is

```
The output is: [{'Company Name': ' ELEVEN', 'Department': '7', 'Ad Posted To': 'MATUN SIGNNATURE', 'Publication References': 'AGOSTI, annonce n°1125\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'}]
```

Is there something I am missing in my code? 
Thank you.

In the code below I omitted some information in the url and header. Hopefully the code below should be enough to explain the situation.

```
    import requests
    from lxml import html
    import csv


    data = []
    for i in range(1, 51, 1):
        print('page: %s' % i)
        headers = {
             //header info
    }
    response = requests.get(url)
    _txt = response.text
    data.append(_txt)
    print(len(data))
    # print(data)
# parsing the html

for text in data:
    doc = html.fromstring(text)
    container = doc.xpath("//tr[contains(@class, 'pair')]")[1]
    company_name = container.xpath('.//dt[contains(text(), "Dénomination sociale :")]/following-sibling::dd[1]/text()')
    # publication_date = container.xpath(".//td[@class='colonnel']/text()")
    #ad_category = container.xpath('.//dt[contains(text(), "Catégorie d'annonce :")]/following-sibling::dd[1]/text()')
    department = container.xpath('.//dt[contains(text(), "Département :")]/following-sibling::dd[1]/text()')
    ad_posted_to = container.xpath('.//dt[contains(text(), "Annonce déposée au :")]/following-sibling::dd[1]/text()')
    publication_references = container.xpath('.//dt[contains(text(), "Références de publication :")]/following-sibling::dd[1]/text()')
    # json output
    resp = {}
    output = []
    for info in zip(company_name, department, ad_posted_to, publication_references):
        resp['Company Name'] = info[0]
        resp['Department'] = info[1]
        resp['Ad Posted To'] = info[2]
        resp['Publication References'] = info[3]
        print(resp)
output.append(resp)
print("The output is:",output)
```

Comment: `append` *inside* the loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are overwriting `output` with each iteration. Try putting `output = []` outside of the loop `for text in data`.

For example:

```py
output = []
for text in data:
    doc = html.fromstring(text)
    container = doc.xpath("//tr[contains(@class, 'pair')]")[1]
    company_name = container.xpath('.//dt[contains(text(), "Dénomination sociale :")]/following-sibling::dd[1]/text()')
    # publication_date = container.xpath(".//td[@class='colonnel']/text()")
    #ad_category = container.xpath('.//dt[contains(text(), "Catégorie d'annonce :")]/following-sibling::dd[1]/text()')
    department = container.xpath('.//dt[contains(text(), "Département :")]/following-sibling::dd[1]/text()')
    ad_posted_to = container.xpath('.//dt[contains(text(), "Annonce déposée au :")]/following-sibling::dd[1]/text()')
    publication_references = container.xpath('.//dt[contains(text(), "Références de publication :")]/following-sibling::dd[1]/text()')
    # json output
    resp = {}
    for info in zip(company_name, department, ad_posted_to, publication_references):
        resp['Company Name'] = info[0]
        resp['Department'] = info[1]
        resp['Ad Posted To'] = info[2]
        resp['Publication References'] = info[3]
        print(resp)
    output.append(resp)
print("The output is:",output)
```

Comment: Thank you. I combined you answer with the one below, and my code worked like a charm. :) Thanks again

Comment: Great, if you'd like to select one of them as the answer, please click the arrow icon next to the response.

Answer (score 1):

You are taking just the last one. Try adding `resp` to output inside `for` loop also restart `resp` dict

```
for info in zip(company_name, department, ad_posted_to, publication_references):
    resp = {}
    resp['Company Name'] = info[0]
    resp['Department'] = info[1]
    resp['Ad Posted To'] = info[2]
    resp['Publication References'] = info[3]
    print(resp)
    output.append(resp)
```

Comment: Worked like a charm :) Thanks